# Recommended enterprise server for build, CI and CPU intensive tasks

Tags: processor, server, windows, compatibility, quiet-computing

I'm looking for a server capable of performing the following tasks:

- Can be used as a build-server (we have several developers using
  Microsoft Team Foundation Services)
- Continuous integration of massive projects
- Perform CPU intensive tasks (mostly user-mode data parsing)
- Can be used for load balancing of other stations

**Requirements:**

- The server must be able to run hundreds of processes simultaneously (therefore must include large amount of cores [16+])
- Must contain at least 64 GB of RAM
- Better not include an OS (we already have license for Windows Server so we don't want to pay extra money for operating system)
- We don't need a lot of storage but we must have at least 1/2 TB of SSD.
- Better be quiet.

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What form factor? Rackmount? Tower? Will it be in a server room or a shared work area?

Comment: @NoahL, regarding the form factor, I will be glad for any suggestion right now. regarding the storage place, it will eventually be servers room.

Comment: Here's a good site to start. This is for an HP workstation, but configured correctly, it will have more power than most servers and will run quietly (because it's destined to be run in an office). http://store.hp.com/us/en/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&urlLangId=&langId=-1&storeId=10151&catEntryId=839174&quantity=1